# Convert SVG (which contains multi-code emoji) to PNG fails

Tags: svg, png, emoji, python-unicode

I'm able to convert a very large SVG which contain emoji's into PNG or even PDF.

But I struggle to get it working with multi-code emoji's

Please find below an extract with just a few lines.

The one that fails to convert is:

```
<text x="20" y="110" font-size="20px" >\U0001F1E8\U0001F1ED</text>
    </svg>
```

Please find below an extract with just a few lines.

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
from reportlab.graphics import renderPDF, renderPM

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>

<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg width="200px" height="200px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<text x="20" y="20" font-size="20px" >Test</text>
<text x="20" y="50" font-size="20px" >\uF1E8\uF1ED</text>
<text x="20" y="80" font-size="20px" >\U0001F1E8\U0001F1ED</text>
<text x="20" y="110" font-size="20px" ></text>
</svg>"""

with open('test.svg', 'w') as file:
    file.write(data)
    file.close()

drawing = svg2rlg("test.svg")
renderPDF.drawToFile(drawing, "test.pdf")
renderPM.drawToFile(drawing, "test.png", fmt="PNG")
```

Many thanks in advance for any hint and have a nice day:-)

Comment: OK, no problem, I just removed that font :-)

Comment: So let's forget about the pdf, the heart emoji and the color here, so I removed those lines.
Let us concentrate on the flag a multi-code point emoji or also called graphemes 
No matter what notation I use, either \uF1E8\uF1ED or \U0001F1E8\U0001F1ED or the emojiitself, only the pasted emoji seem to work in the SVG but not if converted to PNG, in the PNG I get two black squares instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I used the [html2image](https://pypi.org/project/html2image/) Python module which converts the SVG (including embedded Emoji's) nicely to a PNG image.