# Emojies Error plotly kaleido static image export does not support emojis

Tags: python, plotly, emoji

https://github.com/misrori/goldhandyoutube/blob/main/aranykez.ipynb
In colab it works when you display.
[image]

But when you export it does not
[image]

```py
from goldhand import *
tw = Tw()
t = GoldHand('TSLA')
p = t.plotly_last_year(tw.get_plotly_title('TSLA'))
p.update_layout(height=1080, width=1920)
p.write_image("fig1.png")
```

Comment: The font declaration is hardwired into plotly_last_year() function in GoldHand. the font stack is `Courier New, monospace`. Displayed in a browser, browsers will use inbuilt font fallback mechanisms. But that doesn't exist in the library generating the png file, so Courier New is used, and since it doesn't have the glyphs you need you get the .notdef glyph instead. Easiest solution is modify fontstack in GoldHand source and build package.

Comment: Correct display of emoji in Colab is by accident, rather than by design.

Answer (score 1):

I did some testing: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1lA29VpoH-CefxR1sCPsCX54fe1q-vQsL#scrollTo=9kO91brNR5Xx

My hunch on why exporting the plotly chart to PNG directly is that the unicode is not exported, like below:

[image: chart exported to png, emojis are rendering as []]

Justification: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-emojis-show-up-as-boxes-on-my-computer

> Any character for which your system does not have the font to render, or which is not defined in the document character set, shows up as a box on your screen. Emojis are Unicode characters, with up to 4-byte codes, so the character encoding for a document must be at least UTF-8 to properly render them. If the document header specifies an ASCII encoding like ISO-8859–1 (Western Europe latin character set), emojis will not be displayed. Also, Unicode gets revised all the time to add new character codes, so older systems that don’t get upgraded won’t be able to display new ones.

I think it may have something to do with this [cannot display character character in static image #157](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/157) as this one involves using a character from Chinese language set and it renders the same []. However this is just speculation.

The current workaround I found is to save the plotly chart either as an SVG

```
t = GoldHand('TSLA')
p = t.plotly_last_year(tw.get_plotly_title('TSLA'))
p.update_layout(height=1080, width=1920)
p.write_image("fig1.svg")
```

[image: screenshot of SVG from web browser]

or as an HTML document and then going inside and exporting it as a PNG.

```
import plotly
t = GoldHand('TSLA')
p = t.plotly_last_year(tw.get_plotly_title('TSLA'))
plotly.offline.plot(p, filename='chart.html')
```

[image: screenshot of chart saved as html document with export to pdf tooltip active]

Note, I also tried using the library mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73702959/convert-svg-which-contains-multi-code-emoji-to-png-fails) (html2image) but I kept running into an issue where the output file `screenshot.png` would not write to disk. This issue may be limited only to colab where I was doing the testing.